# Signed transaction as program input parameter

Tags: solana-program, transactions

Is it even possible to accept a signed transaction as an input parameter for a program?

For example, there's an API which gives a signed transactions as a result. I need to execute that transaction alongside my own transaction (kinda wrap two transactions into another) so if either of them fail, none should get executed.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to execute that transaction alongside my own transaction (kinda wrap two transactions into another) so if either of them fail, none should get executed.

This should be possible. Technically, you would be executing two *instructions* inside a single transaction, and the transaction would revert if either of the instructions reverted. This distinction is shown in the below diagram, taken from [here](https://blog.labeleven.dev/anatomy-of-solana-program-invocations-using-anchor):

[image: anatomy of a solana tx]

Simply, instructions are what actually make state changes in the blockchain, and can be thought of as calls to programs. For example, a user can transfer their SPL tokens through a [transfer instruction](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/f97a3dc7cf0e6b8e346d473a8c9d02de7b213cfd/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L107). Transactions are packages of instructions that users send to validators.

A tutorial for sending multiple instructions in a single transaction can be found in the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-add-a-memo-to-a-transaction).

Comment: thanks! it all makes sense. But the problem is that the API gives already signed transaction. I can't do anything with it, otherwise it will invalidate the signature. Hence the question is how do I pack a transaction inside another transaction.

Comment: If you can't re-sign a new transaction, it's not possible because all transactions are independent of each other and only instructions can have guaranteed atomicity